# Why do I get "library not found for -lPods" in XCode

Tags: ios, cocoapods

after a few weeks of developing an iOS app I wanted to deploy the App on my test device (used the simulator before). Since that I always get this error:

```
    ld: library not found for -lPods
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now it doesn't even works in the simulator.
I already tried to reinstall all pods and searched the billions of threads. But I don't get it to work.
This is my Podfile:

```
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    platform :ios, '9.1'
    target 'be2gether'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Alamofire', '~>3.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
    project '../be2gether.xcodeproj'
```

I open the project by using the .xcworkspace file.
Already tried to clean the project or alt + clean the project and deleted the derived data in Xcode.
I would post the build options but I don't know which are important for the problem. How can i get the project back working?
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Did you `pod install`?  Did you restart Xcode?  Are you 100% certain you're opening the `.xcworkspace` and opening the right `.xcworkspace`?  Is this error only happening for trying to build to simulator?  Does it work for building to devices?  What have you changed since the last time it did work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I had the same problem.
Try to create a blank project and see if it compiles.
In my case the workspace was broken. This fixed it.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It turned out that inside of "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" libPods -XXX.a was many times. I deleted the ones that didn't belong to my target and it worked. Below an image that my help you to understand how I solve it. BTW I have cocoaPod 1.0.1 and xCode 8 beta 5.
[image: Project->Target->Basic->Linked Frameworks and Libraries]

Answer (score 0):

Go To Terminal And Install Your Pod Again Or Update That it

Answer (score -1):

Delete the pod references from your project and install it again!!